# Custom Javascript Component: Using @StyleSheet produces script error in IE8

Tags: java, javascript, css, vaadin, vaadin7

I have created a custom javascript component in vaadin. I have added several external stylesheets using `@StyleSheet` annotation. The component works fine, but in IE8 it shows script errors. The number of script errors is equal to the number of external CSS included using the annotation.

The error is: *Object doesn't support this action.*

[image]

How do I resolve this?

**UI Class:**

```
package com.example.example;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("example")
public class ExampleUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = ExampleUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);
        MyComp mycomponent = new MyComp();      
        layout.addComponent(mycomponent);
    }

}
```

---

**Component**

**Server part: MyComp.java**

```
package com.example.example;

import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript;
import com.vaadin.annotations.StyleSheet;
import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractJavaScriptComponent;


@JavaScript({"component.js","component-connector.js"})
@StyleSheet({"Stylesheet1.css"})
public class MyComp  extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Override
     protected MyCompState getState() {
         return (MyCompState) super.getState();
     }
}
```

**Client Part: component.js**

```
var mylibrary = mylibrary || {};

mylibrary.Comp = function(element) {
    element.innerHTML = "<div>hello</div>";
};
```

**Connector: component-connector.js**

```
window.com_example_example_MyComp =
function() {
    var mycomponent = new mylibrary.Comp(this.getElement());

    this.onStateChange = function(e) {};

};
```

**State: MyCompState.java**

```
package com.example.example;

import com.vaadin.shared.ui.JavaScriptComponentState;

public class MyCompState extends JavaScriptComponentState{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

---

**Stylesheets**

**Stylesheet1.css**

```
div {
}
```

---

Comment: I assume you are writing a GWT application. Try to make a pretty compile and take a look at the compiled source. Just to ensure: Is the number of included CSS files > 100 ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the source code. Number of css files < 10.

Comment: I face same issue in IE when by mistake name of object is already exists property/object/keyword. like i name method selection() which is not working, when i make it myselection error got resolved.

Comment: what vaadin version are you using?

Comment: @cfrick: it is 7.1.11

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your JavaScript variable names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Problem is where I add external css with @StyleSheet annotation. If I remove `@StyleSheet({"Stylesheet1.css"})` from the code, it will work fine. My question is : Is there a way of added external css to custom components, that does not give script errors?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could take a look at https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/annotations/StyleSheet.html for some tips.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your css code is being included as javascript files.
The generated source probably looks like 
`<script src="css_file.css"></script>`

when it should look like
`<link href="css_file.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Can you show us the generated html file?